# Macro for hiding values in a Data Validation list based on value selected from another Data Validation list

Tags: vba, validation, excel

I need your help in writing a macro for displaying only unique values in the next column (For suppose B column) which should be in a list format, based on the value selected from a Data validation list (For suppose, which is in A column).

I want to be more specific by providing the data I am using for this macro, as I am still a beginner in writing these macros, I would really appreciate your help.

---

**Process Definition**

Process Planning

New process initiatives

Amendment of existing process

QMS Feedback received from Stakeholders

Analysis of the Feedback received

Process reviews

Process roll-out activities

Process Piloting

Process integration workshops

New Process Trainings

**Process Implementation**

Facilitation to support functions

**Audit Management**

Audit Scheduling

Execution. Coordinating and conducting audits

Audit Report preparation and support

Corrective action and preventive action - followup

Audit status update

Audit Analysis

Audit Closure

**Metrics**

Metrics collation facilitation

Metrics collection for project and support

Metrics Analysis for project and support

**Management Review**

MRM scheduling

MRM presentation preparation

Pre-MRM

Coordinating and conducting Management Review

Action Items followups

**Process Training**

Orientation Training

Internal Auditor Training

Process Training

---

So I want to create a data validation list in column B from 'B4:B25' with all the headings given in bold above and another data validation list in column C from 'C4:C5' with all the respective data below each heading. If I select "Process Definition" from 'B4' DV list, then I want the data below heading1 i.e., "Process Planning,New process initiatives..... and so on" to be displayed in the data validation list in 'C4'.

Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Comment: Do a search with keywords `excel data validation list dependent` finds http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have a dropdown already present in column A with values "a" & "b", use **Workbook_SheetChange** event in VBA to populate the value in Column B based on the value select in Column A:

e.g.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then 'To run only when the value is changed in column A
        Cells(Target.Row, 2).Select
        Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = ""  'Initializes value of dependent dropdown to blank
        If Target.Value = "a" Then
        'Add 1,2,3,4 to dependent dropdown if value of Column A is "a"
            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="1,2,3,4" 'Change 1,2,3,4 to values that you need for a
                .IgnoreBlank = False
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        ElseIf Target.Value = "b" Then
        'Add 1,2,3,4 to dependent dropdown if value of Column A is "b"
            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="5,6,7,8" 'Change 5,6,7,8 to values that you need for b
                .IgnoreBlank = False
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit:
All you needed was to change the target value(`Target.Value`) and the values in `Formula1` given in my code to those which you require. Something like this will be able to help you:

```
If Target.Value = "Process Definition" Then
'Create dependent dropdown when value of Column A is "Process Definition"
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="Process Planning,New process initiatives,Amendment of existing process, and so on.."
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
ElseIf Target.Value = "Process Implementation" Then
'Create dependent dropdown when value of Column A is "Process Implementation"
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="Facilitation to support functions"
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
ElseIf Target.Value = "Audit Management" Then
'Create dependent dropdown when value of Column A is "Audit Management"
    With Selection.Validation
        <similar code as above>
    End With
ElseIf...and so on..
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

You can create first dropdown (Process Definition,Process Implementation,Audit Management etc.) using Data Validation option in Data Tab of Excel or by using another VBA code (documentations for both are easily available on internet). You can refer Axel Richter's link for the same as well.

Comment: Hi rusk. I have edited my question by providing more specific data. Being a beginner in macros, I am unable to apply your example to my data. Really appreciate your help.